# JavaScript Regexp.test returning an unexpected result

Tags: javascript, regex

It's probably something I am doing wrong or am not understanding correctly, but I am trying to figure out why 'teest' is not returning true in the following test. It seems like it should return true on each of the following cases:

```
var r = RegExp("te", "gi");
r.test("test");
// true
r.test("teest");
// false
r.test("teset");
// true
var r = RegExp("tee", "gi");
r.test("teesting");
// true
r.test("teeest");
// true
```

Comment: Which browser? Returns true here: http://jsfiddle.net/wGLSx/

Comment: Why use the `g` flag with `.test`?  Makes no sense.  It's either there or not, doesn't matter if it's there multiple times.

Comment: remove the `g` and it'll work

Comment: I am using chrome and appcelerator, and removing g worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments it was pointed out that I needed to remove the g. Which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you found your solution, but just in case you care: when you use the global option (g), `r.lastIndex` is updated to `2` after the first `test()`.  The following `test()` examines the input string starting at index 2, which doesn't match the regular expression:

```
var r = RegExp('te', 'gi');
// r.lastIndex == 0
r.test('test');
// true, r.lastIndex == 2
r.test('test');
// false, r.lastIndex == 0
```

As you already discovered, you can simply remove the global option.  You could also reset the value of `r.lastIndex`, or you could loop over each input string until `test()` returns false.